# Закрепить заголовок вверху блока с прокруткой

Tags: html, css, css3, html5

```css
body {
  margin: 0 0 0 0;
  padding: 0 0 60px 0;
  font-size: 16px;
}

h2 {
  color: #CC0033;
}

div {
  width: 200px;
  /* фиксированная ширина */
  height: 300px;
  /* фиксированная высота */
  border: 1px solid #555;
  padding: 4px;
  margin: 4px;
  float: left;
}

.AutoDiv {
  overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<DIV class="AutoDiv">

  <H2>auto</H2>

  <P>Товарищи! начало повседневной работы по формированию позиции играет важную роль в формировании систем массового участия. Значимость этих проблем настолько очевидна, что постоянный количественный рост и сфера нашей активности требуют определения и уточнения
    новых предложений. Таким образом укрепление и развитие структуры представляет собой интересный эксперимент проверки модели развития. Задача организации, в особенности же новая модель организационной деятельности в значительной степени обуславливает
    создание системы обучения кадров, соответствует насущным потребностям.</P>

  <P>Разнообразный и богатый опыт укрепление и развитие структуры позволяет оценить значение направлений прогрессивного развития. Таким образом дальнейшее развитие различных форм деятельности позволяет выполнять важные задания по разработке новых предложений.
    Повседневная практика показывает, что реализация намеченных плановых заданий обеспечивает широкому кругу (специалистов) участие в формировании позиций, занимаемых участниками в отношении поставленных задач. Значимость этих проблем настолько очевидна,
    что укрепление и развитие структуры представляет собой интересный эксперимент проверки существенных финансовых и административных условий. Таким образом постоянный количественный рост и сфера нашей активности позволяет оценить значение форм развития.
    Идейные соображения высшего порядка, а также рамки и место обучения кадров обеспечивает широкому кругу (специалистов) участие в формировании позиций, занимаемых участниками в отношении поставленных задач.</P>

</DIV>
```

Как сделать, так чтобы `scroll` был в таком положении, до конца, но, когда скроллишь, заголовок остается на месте, а скролиться только текст.

Comment: Я не распарсил, что значит фраза «scroll был в таком положении, до конца»?

Comment: То что скролиться должен тест, но auto должно оставаться на месте

Comment: Всё равно не понял, ну да ладно

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Во всех современных браузерах [поддерживается](http://caniuse.com/#search=sticky) (в Edge завезут чуть позже) `position: sticky`, суть которого примерно такова: когда до элемента не докрутили, он стоит себе в тексте как обычный элемент, а когда докручивают, то применяется положение, прописанное в `top` или `bottom`, и элемент закрепляется и игнорирует прокрутку. В вашем случае можно прописать `sticky` с `top: 0`, чтобы закрепить заголовок вверху div'а. Пример (стили элементов допилите самостоятельно под свою задачу):

```css
.AutoDiv > h2 {
  margin: 0 -4px;
  padding: 16px 4px;

  position: -webkit-sticky; /* для Safari */
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  background-color: rgba(240, 240, 255, 0.9); /* прозрачно для наглядности */
}

div {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 1px solid #555;
  padding: 0 4px;
}

.AutoDiv {
  overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<DIV class="AutoDiv">

  <H2>auto</H2>

  <P>Товарищи! начало повседневной работы по формированию позиции играет важную роль в формировании систем массового участия. Значимость этих проблем настолько очевидна, что постоянный количественный рост и сфера нашей активности требуют определения и уточнения
    новых предложений. Таким образом укрепление и развитие структуры представляет собой интересный эксперимент проверки модели развития. Задача организации, в особенности же новая модель организационной деятельности в значительной степени обуславливает
    создание системы обучения кадров, соответствует насущным потребностям.</P>

  <P>Разнообразный и богатый опыт укрепление и развитие структуры позволяет оценить значение направлений прогрессивного развития. Таким образом дальнейшее развитие различных форм деятельности позволяет выполнять важные задания по разработке новых предложений.
    Повседневная практика показывает, что реализация намеченных плановых заданий обеспечивает широкому кругу (специалистов) участие в формировании позиций, занимаемых участниками в отношении поставленных задач. Значимость этих проблем настолько очевидна,
    что укрепление и развитие структуры представляет собой интересный эксперимент проверки существенных финансовых и административных условий. Таким образом постоянный количественный рост и сфера нашей активности позволяет оценить значение форм развития.
    Идейные соображения высшего порядка, а также рамки и место обучения кадров обеспечивает широкому кругу (специалистов) участие в формировании позиций, занимаемых участниками в отношении поставленных задач.</P>

</DIV>
```

Если же нужна поддержка старых браузеров, то тут малой кровью с каким-нибудь `fixed` не обойтись, нужно велосипедить на скриптах. Но это пусть кто-нибудь другой ответ напишет

Answer (score 1):

Как я понял вы хотите так, немного надо менять `css`

```css
body {
  margin: 0 0 0 0;
  padding: 0 0 60px 0;
  font-size: 16px;
}

h2 {
  color: #CC0033;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
}

.AutoDiv {
  position: relative;
  width: 200px;
  /* фиксированная ширина */
  height: 300px;
  /* фиксированная высота */
  border: 1px solid #555;
  padding: 4px;
  margin: 4px;
  float: left;
  overflow: auto;
}
.content{
  margin-top: 50px;
}
```

```html
<DIV class="AutoDiv">

  <H2>auto</H2>

  <div class="content">
    <P>Товарищи! начало повседневной работы по формированию позиции играет важную роль в формировании систем массового участия. Значимость этих проблем настолько очевидна, что постоянный количественный рост и сфера нашей активности требуют определения и уточнения
    новых предложений. Таким образом укрепление и развитие структуры представляет собой интересный эксперимент проверки модели развития. Задача организации, в особенности же новая модель организационной деятельности в значительной степени обуславливает
    создание системы обучения кадров, соответствует насущным потребностям.</P>

  <P>Разнообразный и богатый опыт укрепление и развитие структуры позволяет оценить значение направлений прогрессивного развития. Таким образом дальнейшее развитие различных форм деятельности позволяет выполнять важные задания по разработке новых предложений.
    Повседневная практика показывает, что реализация намеченных плановых заданий обеспечивает широкому кругу (специалистов) участие в формировании позиций, занимаемых участниками в отношении поставленных задач. Значимость этих проблем настолько очевидна,
    что укрепление и развитие структуры представляет собой интересный эксперимент проверки существенных финансовых и административных условий. Таким образом постоянный количественный рост и сфера нашей активности позволяет оценить значение форм развития.
    Идейные соображения высшего порядка, а также рамки и место обучения кадров обеспечивает широкому кругу (специалистов) участие в формировании позиций, занимаемых участниками в отношении поставленных задач.</P>
  </div>

</DIV>
```

Comment: Несмотря на то, что вы прописали `position: relative` диву, положение `fixed` всё равно высчитывается относительно страницы, из-за чего в других случаях заголовок может легко вылезти за пределы дива

Comment: @andreymal Да я с начало по другому хотел писать код, потом изменил, а это случайно осталось, Да в `других случаях`.

Comment: И да, если вместо «auto» написать заголовок подлиннее, например «Съешь же ещё этих мягких французских булок, да выпей чаю», то всё становится совсем плохо

Comment: @andreymal Если вам нужно другое то напишите вопрос новый для себя.

Comment: Пилить по новому вопросу для каждого нового текста заголовка? Абсурд какой-то.